# Reponse.Redirect doesn't work immediately C#

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, response.redirect

I have the following C# code:

```
string ProfileID, UserID;
try
{
    ProfileID = Request.QueryString["ProfileID"].ToString();
    string SelectQuery;
    DataSet ds;
    try
    {
        UserID = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        if (ProfileID == UserID)
        {
            Response.Redirect("user/Default.aspx", true);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
           //some code here
        }
    }
    finally
    {

      //some code here

    }
}
catch {
    Response.Redirect("DoesNotExists.aspx");
}
```

The problem here is that if the condition is true (`if (ProfileID == UserID)`),  the code cotinue running and instead of redirect in this line   :                        `Response.Redirect("user/Default.aspx", true);` 
the redicet is in this line : `Response.Redirect("DoesNotExists.aspx");`

My question is how can I fix it.

Wish for help, thanks!

Comment: could you capture the actual exception? `catch (Exception ex)` would catch all exceptions and would tell you whats going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot redirect in a `Try-Catch` because a `ThreadAbortedException`  is thrown. You need to pass `false` to [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) to do so.

> Boolean Indicates whether execution of the
>   current page should terminate.

So either save the redirect location and redirect after the try-catch or use `Response.Redirect(url, false)`.

```
string ProfileID, UserID, redirectUrl;
try
{
    ProfileID = Request.QueryString["ProfileID"].ToString();
    string SelectQuery;
    DataSet ds;
    try
    {
        UserID = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        if (ProfileID == UserID)
        {
            redirectUrl = "user/Default.aspx";
        }
        else
        {
           //some code here
        }
    }
    finally
    {

      //some code here
    }
}
catch 
{
    redirectUrl = "DoesNotExists.aspx";
}

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUrl))
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

Comment: Just caught this question on my phone and booted up SO on my laptop to  post pretty much exactly this.

Comment: Thank you, but now, when the code is in the catch (Response.Redirect("DoesNotExists.aspx");) I get this error message: "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.", why?

Comment: @NaveTseva: What are you doing in `//some code here`? It seems that you are writing to the HttpResponse. You should not use `Response.Write` normally.

Comment: I didn't used any other respone.somthing in any other place of the code

Comment: @NaveTseva: What approach have you used? If you use the `false`-redirect approach you must not call `Response.Redirect` a second time. Otherwise you get this exception.